# react-table default height issue and adaptive styling

Tags: css, reactjs, react-table

I am using react-table with scrollable columns and header - made similar to https://codesandbox.io/s/kowzlm5jp7?file=/index.js:281-310

I set the height in styles in table like

```
        <ReactTableFixedColumns
            showPagination={false}
            defaultPageSize={selectedItemsLength}
            data={selectedItems}
            style={{height: "73vh"}}
            className="-striped -highlight"
            columns={[
```

So the issue when I select only 1 or 2 items table looks very stretched out

[image: table with one item selected]

When I use 73vh - it looks ok but only on my screen (ubuntu chrome) and when I select more than 10-15 items. If less - it is stretched.

On chrome or safari on Mac there are no scroll bars visible for some reason.

I am really messed with that table, are there any solutions for react-table to look pretty on many devices OR at least not to stretch with 1 or 2 items?

Thank anyone for kind response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fought the stretching by

```
    .ReactTable .rt-thead {
    flex: none !important;
}

.ReactTable .rt-tr {
    flex: none !important;
}

.ReactTable .rt-tr-group {
    flex: none !important;
}
```

Still dunno how to make table looks pretty on mac and ubuntu - what height should I set